# Stacking of data, extracting of value, pushing stack down

Tags: arduino

I might have missed a post for this question or searched the wrong question online so if there is something that answers this question exactly, sorry please link :)

Question: I'm trying to create a array to store a few integers in order,

```
data(1)
data(2)
data(3)
data(4)
data(5)
```

with the array complete, the program finds a average of the integers and then moves the stack up or deletes the oldest (data1) entry and moves the entire thing up by one, so it starts:

```
data(2)
""
data(6)
```

and this continues over in a loop until the software is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stack is a LIFO data structure. It looks like you want to use a queue, which is a FIFO data structure. This can be accomplished using a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). This allows us to use a simple array. An example of the behavior you described in the question can be found in the following code example.

```
uint8_t qhead;
uint8_t qtail;
uint8_t qsize;
const uint8_t qcapacity = 5;
uint8_t qdata[qcapacity];

void queue_enqueue(const uint8_t data)
{
    // Check to make sure that we do not overflow
    if (qsize + 1 > qcapacity)
    {
        return;
    }

    qdata[qhead] = data;

    // Calculate the new head
    qhead = (qhead + 1) % qcapacity;
    qsize++;
}

uint16_t queue_dequeue(void)
{
    // Make sure there is something to dequeue
    if (qsize == 0)
    {
        return 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }

    uint8_t result = qdata[qtail];

    // Calculate the new tail
    qtail = (qtail + 1) % qcapacity;
    qsize--;

    return result;
}

void setup()
{
    qhead = 0;
    qtail = 0;
    qsize = 0;
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t data = /* Input source here */;

    /* Need to fill the queue with qcapacity items first */
    if (qsize < qcapacity)
    {
        queue_enqueue(data);
    }
    else
    {
        /* Calculate the average */
        uint16_t average = 0;
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < qsize; i += 1)
        {
            average += qdata[i];
        }
        average = average / qsize;

        /* Remove the old element */
        queue_dequeue();

        /* Add the new element */
        queue_enqueue(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, pretty simple looking :P